# Get multiple owl carousels respond to next prev event

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'm having problem with my owl carousel navigation. When I click "next" or "prev" all the carousels switching images. I want only the one that i click on to trigger. Below is my current code. Could you help me out?

jQuery(function ($) {

```
var owl = $('.image-slider-properties');
owl.each(function(){
$(this).owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  nav:true,
  autoPlay:false,
  items:1,
  autoWidth:true,
  nav : true,
  navText: [$('.am-next'),$('.am-prev')],
  margin:10,
  responsive:{
      0:{
          items:1
      },
      600:{
          items:1
      },
      1000:{
          items:1
      }
  }
})
});

$('.am-next').click(function() {
  owl.trigger('owl.prev');
})

$('.am-prev').click(function() {
  owl.trigger('owl.next');
})

}
```

Comment: Anyone having a solution for this?

Comment: Problem solved.